# Generate random number after value in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, random

I want my machine to automatically download some files. That doesn't have to be very efficient. So I decided to do this with a bash script.

It works so far when I encode the URL hardly. But I want to get the files retrieved in irregular order and I thought I would use simple variables. How do I get the random number into my variable?

My approach

```
data_link0="https://example.com/target1.html"
data_link1="https://example.com/target2.html"
data_link2="https://example.com/target3.html"
data_link3="https://example.com/target4.html"

useragent0="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1"
useragent1="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.3 Safari/604.5.6"
useragent3="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 7; ) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion"

wget --user-agent="$user_agent[$((RANDOM % 3))]" "$datei_link$((RANDOM % 3))"
```

unfortunately does not work.

Comment: You should know that `$(( RANDOM % k ))` does *not* generate a random number uniformly from `0` to `k - 1`, unless `k` is a power of 2. (Proof: `k` does not divide 32768.) If it is important that your distribution be uniform, you'll need to take extra measures to effect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as you need to retrieve all the urls, a better way would be using [shuf](/questions/tagged/shuf) (GNU/linux coreutils) (or `sort -R` coreutils too):

```
shuf file | xargs wget
```

### File :

```
$ cat file
"https://example.com/target1.html"
"https://example.com/target2.html"
"https://example.com/target3.html"
"https://example.com/target4.html"
```

---

```
man 1 shuf
```

> NAME
>
> shuf - generate random permutations

---

### New comments, new needs, new code :

(requiring random user-agent)

```
$ cat uas
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36 OPR/15.0.1147.100
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

### Code :

```
shuf file | while read url; do
    wget --user-agent="$(shuf -n1 uas)" "$url"
done
```

---

### If you prefer to keep your way (one url) :

```
data_link=(
    "https://example.com/target1.html"
    "https://example.com/target2.html"
    "https://example.com/target3.html"
    "https://example.com/target4.html"
)
user_agent=(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1"
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.3 Safari/604.5.6"
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 7; ) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion"
)

wget --user-agent="${user_agent[RANDOM % ${#user_agent[@]} ]}" "${data_link[RANDOM % ${#data_link[@]}]}"
```

---

### Your way for all urls and user-agent (both randomized) :

```
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#data_link[@]} -1)) | shuf); do
    wget -U "${user_agent[RANDOM % ${#user_agent[@]}]}" "${data_link[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Wow, it runs really good. But ...
… now I can not fill in the option "--user-agent="

How can I fill in an _randomized *user agent*_ from a file?

Comment: Something like `uas=( firefox waterfox chromium opera ); shuf file | xargs wget --user-agent="${uas[ RANDOM % ${#uas[@]}]}"
` (adapt to your needs, this is not real user-agents)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason to prefer `shuf` over `sort -R`?

Comment: Both works, up to OP :) Added it at the beginning of the post

Answer (score 4):

Instead of defining separate variables for each string, define an array. Use `${ar[123]}` to access element 123 of the array `ar` and `${#ar[@]}` to get the size of the array.

```
data_link=(
    "https://example.com/target1.html"
    "https://example.com/target2.html"
    "https://example.com/target3.html"
    "https://example.com/target4.html"
)
user_agent=(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1"
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.3 Safari/604.5.6"
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 7; ) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion"
)

wget --user-agent="${user_agent[RANDOM % ${#user_agent[@]}]}" "${data_link[RANDOM % ${#data_link[@]}]}"
```

Comment: Good if OP want only to retrieve _one url_ at a time ;) (And I get a syntax error)

Comment: And no need `$(( ))` : `uas=( foo bar base); echo "${uas[RANDOM % ${#uas[@]}]}"`

Comment: I tested it, but I get this error  'Syntax error: "(" unexpected'